# Usage of decimal expansion

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I learned about the rigorous construction of rationals as a set of equivalence classes of ordered integers with operations defined on this set. I understand that the decimal expansion is another way to represent the same rational as the sum of other rationals. There happen to be rationals with repeating decimal expansions. What bothers me is why is this decimal expansion representation of a rational number is used by people when we have a careful constructed rational number system? When we represent a number with repeating digit in computers we have to give it a finite decimal expansion thus obtaining a different number compared to the one we wanted to represent. For example if we have 1 thing(that can be divided in 60 equal parts) and we want to divide it in equal parts(suppose 3), when we use rational number system as constructed we get 20 as result. But what if we wanted to use decimal expansion to calculate the same thing? Then 0.33(for example) multiplied by 60 gives 19.8 which is not equal to 20. Then why people saw something good in this decimal expansion representation of rational numbers and constantly use it? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is convenient, and if we do not truncate too early, we get answers that are correct for all practical purposes.

Comment: "For example if we have 1 dollar and we want to divide it in equal parts(suppose 3), when we use rational number system as constructed we get 20 as result ..." What????

Comment: @André Nicolas Could you please elaborate this in an answer? What do you mean by truncating too early? In the example above we truncated the expansion because we needed to use it to compute the result? What about obtaining a wrong result?

Comment: If we use $0.3333333$ the result will be close enough.

Comment: @William I gave it just as an example considering the dollar to be divided in 60 equal parts. Think of it as a thing that can be divided in 60 equal parts.

Comment: @André Nicolas But it will never be the exact result which is 20.

Comment: @J.M I am confused. Why does dividing a dollar into 60 equal parts give you 20?

Comment: Agreed. But if your bill is for $19.99997$ dollars, you will be expected to fork over a $20$.

Comment: @William 60 = 20 x 3. We want that one thing that is composed of 60 equal parts to divide in 3 parts. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Now I am utterly confused.

Comment: I wanted to build a circular pool of 5 meters radius. I asked my local home depot for 32 meters of building materials. The clerk objected to my wastefulness and said I only needed $10\pi$ meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Then why people saw something good in this decimal expansion representation of rational numbers and constantly use it?"

One reason is that it's easy to add decimal numbers, but to add two fractions you have to find a common denominator. Consider calculating $${1\over5}+{1\over7}+{1\over8}+{1\over9}+{1\over11}+{1\over13}$$ by finding a common denominator, and see what large numbers emerge, even though all the numbers in the problems are small. Compare that to doing it using decimals.

Comment: What about approximating a repeating rational by a finite decimal expansion and then performing operations on it? This way we obtain incorrect results.

Comment: If you want the exact answer, you could stcik to the fractions, or you could convert to decimal, perform the operations, and then convert back to a fraction using the continued fractions method. But very often a 3- or 5- or 10-place decimal approximation to the exact answer is good enough for one's purposes.